# For an SPA should you have your login page seperate from the root url?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, single-page-application

Is it bad practice to have your login page as the root url and not a seperate page? ie

site.com/
vs
site.com/login or site.com/auth

I understand the app architecture and functionality may make the most sense to use /login or /auth but is there any best practice i would be violating by making the login the root url?

Comment: The root URL usually is reserved for the home page or redirects to the homepage so people have an idea what your website is about. If it resolves to your login page a lot of people might think it is a restricted page and leave the page. But this is just an opinion, this question might be a little bit too opinion based for SO

Comment: its an internal webapp, blocked off to everyone expect people we give credentials to

Comment: I honestly don't think it matters in that case. It is fairly common to have the first page as login for internal apps. However I would still have /login as a separate page and redirect ""->/login

Answer (score -1):

I see two issues here.

1. The login page should be seperate from the SPA page.

I think downloading any pieces to the client past the login page, before logging in would introduce security flaws, so do not do it.

2. The login page should not be the root page.

For the same reason as @sinanspd mentioned, if there must be a login have it not as the root.

Comment: with an SPA the login page has to exist somewhere in the app, im not sure what you mean? its an internal webapp, blocked off to everyone expect people we give credentials.

Comment: well what I mean is in the case of a SPA (Single Page Application), the login should be outside of the SPA.  For instance if you were using angular you might expose endpoints that are not meant to be visible until after login.

Comment: do you mean the login page should be hosted seperately from the spa code? all of the examples i see for SPA auth use a login page within their app code. https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/tree/dev/examples/demo/pages

Comment: I see it is written in Vue, which I am not familiar with.